# Not able to inspect logout button for <a href="/index.php?r=site%2Flogout"></a> this tag

Tags: xpath

I can't find the 1 matching node  for `<a href="/index.php?r=site%2Flogout"></a>` this code.
I have tried: `//a[@href,'/index.php?r=site%2Flogout']` this is showing incorrect.

Xpath for this code line `<a href="/index.php?r=site%2Flogout"></a>
xpath: //a[@href,'/index.php?r=site%2Flogout']`

Comment: Also I have tried with this //a[contains(@href, '/index.php?r=site%2Flogout')]

Answer (score 0):

change the comma `,` with the equal `=`

```
//a[@href='/index.php?r=site%2Flogout']
```

Comment: can it be the element inside iframe?

Comment: No iframe is used inside

Answer (score 0):

Kindly try below:

//a[contains(@href,'/index.php?r=site%2Flogout')]

Comment: Hey,  You forgot to close this path with ], Anyways I have tried this too, if you can see my previous comments.

Comment: Could you please inspect an element and paste here complete outer html so that we can check it exactly.

Comment: A process of doing it in Firefox - 
1. Right Click on an element and click on inspect element.
2. Then on highlighted source code right click again and copy outer html.

Comment: Here is the outer html code: <a href="/index.php?r=site%2Flogout"><img class="logout-img" src="/themes/frontend/assets/images/sidebar_logos/logout.png" alt="Logo" width="15px">Log Out</a>

Answer (score 0):

As you can see below in my application as well I am having similar outer html and here I am using link text for clicking on it.Could you please try out the same and let me know whether it works out for you or not.

> a class="fxpage-userpanel-button" id="fxpage-userpanel-logoutbutton" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="showConfirm('Are you sure you want to log out?','http://asd/auth/logout?module=module')">
>   Log out

**Try this out:**

driver.findElement(By.linkText("Log Out")).click();

Comment: So It should works with both ways right either using xpath or locator ? with //a[contains(@href, '/index.php?r=site%2Flogout')]  or
//a[@href,'/index.php?r=site%2Flogout']   or(By.linkText("Log Out")).click()